# page AUTO-UPDATE when database changes

Tags: php, ajax, auto-update

At the moment, everything is working fine with the script, I insert data in my database, I refresh and I get the username with the new message. However I'm trying to figure out how to have the message added onto the page as soon as the database is updated without having to refresh.

Simple HTML, Here's where the messages load up

```
<div id="msg">
</div>
```

Whenever the page is done loading, I'm calling AJAX to get the data

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
//AJAX
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "exampleclass.php";
var msg = document.getElementById("msg");
hr.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (hr.readyState==4 && hr.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=hr.responseText;
    }
}
hr.open("GET", url, true);
hr.send();
});
</script>
```

Here is my PHP form that retrieves data

```
<?php
include('inc/connect.php');
$query = "SELECT message, user_name "
   . "FROM chat "
   . "WHERE (user_name='bryan' or user_name='derek') "
   . "AND (user_to='derek' or user_to='bryan')";
while ($retrievedata = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
echo $retrievedata['user_name'].": ".$retrievedata['message']."<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: The easiest way is to make an AJAX server request every minute to check if there are new records. That gives a near real time experience. Another option is to web search long polling or websockets